# Angular 12 Bootstrap 5 ngFor accordion does not close

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to create a ngFor dropdown accordion list in Angular 12 with bootstrap 5. Somehow the accordions stay open and can not be closed.

I hope someone knows how to make the accordion able to close.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

```html
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let category of cateories; let i = index">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" [attr.id]="'heading' + i">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse' + i">
                    {{ category.title }}
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div [attr.id]="'collapse' + i" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let childCategory of category.children">{{ childCategory.title }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use a library with the accordion component? something like `ngx-bootstrap` ?.

Comment: @OwenKelvin Because I need bootstrap 5 atm for future admin panel upgrade. ngx-bootstrap still uses bootstrap 4. I don't want to use bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 5 together.

Comment: Here is the working example with code snippets:
https://therichpost.com/angular-12-bootstrap-5-accordion-with-dynamic-data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Somehow the accordions stay open and can not be closed.

This is because you have not defined any way to make it close. You probably will need to configure JQuery and bootstrap script files ... Not really recommended.

I would recommend you consider using a library for such components, something like [ngx-accordion](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion)

The other solution is to simply hard code the logic to close and open the accordion

You can set a property to track whether the accordion is open. In your TS file

```
openAccordion: boolean[] = []
```

And in your html

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let category of cateories; let i = index">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" [attr.id]="'heading' + i">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button"
            (click)='openAccordion[i] = !openAccordion[i]' data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse' + i">
                {{ category.title }}
            </button>
    </h2>
    <div [attr.id]="'collapse' + i" class="accordion-collapse collapse" [class.show]='openAccordion[i]'
      [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let childCategory of category.children">{{ childCategory.title }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Sample Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a8ujwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The other option is to include the bootstrap js file. Below is a demo of how this can be implemented

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionContainer">
  <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let category of cateories; let i = index">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" [id]="'heading' + i">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse' + i">
       {{ category.title }}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div [id]="'collapse' + i" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i"
      data-bs-parent="#accordionContainer">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let childCategory of category.children">{{ childCategory.title }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**See Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsto3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you, but bootstrap 5 doesn't use JQuery anymore. If I don't use ngFor, everything works perfectly. I'm still waiting for ngx to upgrade to bootstrap 5.

Comment: I have added the approach without any binding